# \label-\ref consecutively numbered theorems using varioref

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, varioref

I hope all definitions, lemmas, theorems, propositions and corollaries are numbered consecutively. The code as below. 
My trouble is: when I reference, like `\ref{<lemma 4>}`, get 'definition 4'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newtheorem{definition}                {definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}       [definition]{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}         [definition]{lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}     [definition]{corollary}

\labelformat{definition}   {definition~#1}
\labelformat{theorem}      {theorem~#1}
\labelformat{lemma}        {lemma~#1}
\labelformat{corollary}    {corollary~#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1}
$i^2=-1$.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t2}
$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{l3}
$a+b=b+a$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}\label{t4}
$a(b+c)=ab+ac$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}\label{c5}
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$.
\end{corollary}

We use \ref{d1} and \ref{l3} get \ref{t2}, \ref{t4}, \ref{c5}.
\end{document}
```

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: `varioref` does not care about `definition` being a shared counter. In each case `definition` is increased by `\refstepcounter` and thereby the labels are always using `definition`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see `varioref` does not know that there's a different theorem in action -- all use the shared counter named `definition`, `\refstepcounter` increases the `definition` counter, leaving `\@currentlabel` to be `definition`, which leads to the 'wrong' label format then.

I am applying `\DeclareCoupledCounters` from `xassoccnt` package to get coupled counters, which is similar to the concept of shared counters but allows separate labels for each of them and thereby giving `varioref` the opportunity to grab the correct labelformat then. Caveat here: There are four counters now...

As an alternative solution `cleveref` can be used, by defining `crefname` for individual entities, using `\cref{...}` instead of `\ref` and overwritting the label type with `\label[lemma]{l1}` for example, but this can get tedious for a lot of definitions/theorems etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newtheorem{definition}{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{corollary}

\DeclareCoupledCounters{definition,lemma,theorem,corollary}  

\usepackage{varioref}

\labelformat{definition}{definition~#1}
\labelformat{theorem}{theorem~#1}
\labelformat{lemma}{lemma~#1}
\labelformat{corollary}{corollary~#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1}
$i^2=-1$.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t2}
$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label{l3}
$a+b=b+a$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}\label{t4}
$a(b+c)=ab+ac$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}\label{c5}
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$.
\end{corollary}

We use \ref{d1} and \ref{l3} get \ref{t2}, \ref{t4}, \ref{c5}.
\end{document}
```

Alternate version with `cleveref`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\newtheorem{definition}{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{corollary}

\usepackage{cleveref}

% Not really necessary, since cleveref defines them already, but for demonstration only 
%\crefname{definition}{definition}{definitions}
%\Crefname{definition}{Definition}{Definitions}  % for upper case 
%\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmata}
%\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmata}
%\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
%Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
%\crefname{corollary}{corollary}{corollaries}
%\Crefname{corollary}{Corollary}{Corollaries}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1}
$i^2=-1$.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label[theorem]{t2}
$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}\label[lemma]{l3}
$a+b=b+a$.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}\label[theorem]{t4}
$a(b+c)=ab+ac$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}\label[corollary]{c5}
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$.
\end{corollary}

We use \cref{d1} and \cref{l3} get \cref{t2}, \cref{t4}, \cref{c5}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget that `\cref` can take multiple arguments, letting you write something such as `We use \cref{d1,l3} and get \cref{t2,t4,c5}.`

Comment: @Mico: Well, I never forget this  (oh, my nose grows ;-))

Comment: Thank you for your efficient answer! Also to thank the answer @Mico has been deleted.

Comment: @Mico: Please undelete your answer -- it uses `cleveref` too, of course, but in another way

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest that you use the power of the `cleveref` package. This package provides a macro called `\cref`, which not only handles the label-assigning job but can even take multiple arguments. (To ease the job of determining which label should be used with which theorem-like environment, I further recommend you load either the `ntheorem` or the `amsthm` package.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem,varioref,cleveref}

\newtheorem{definition}{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{corollary}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1} $i^2=-1$. \end{definition}    
\begin{theorem}\label{t2} $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. \end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\label{l3} $a+b=b+a$. \end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}\label{t4} $a(b+c)=ab+ac$. \end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}\label{c5} $e^{i\pi}+1=0$. \end{corollary}

\noindent
We use \cref{d1,l3} and get \cref{t2,t4,c5}.
\end{document}
```